# How to choose the optimal Bing maps route?

Tags: php, bing-maps

I want to use this script to work out journey distance. Simple enough. Except this returns a different answer from Bing Maps itself. Okay, I understand that. But what I'd like is a way of picking the "best" one. How do I define best? Well the one that Bing would choose. For example, in this case, it's 11.9 miles (and that's the correct one).

However the script thinks it's 182 miles - which is true if it uses a different Shuttleworth/Bedford.

How do I get it to give me the one that Bing would pick?

For the purpose I'm using this script I can't have an "option to choose", it needs to decide for itself.

```
<?php
$from="Bedford";
$to="Shuttleworth";
$load="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.1=$from&wp.2=$to&key=MYAPIKEY&distanceUnit=mile";
$data= file_get_contents($load);
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to get a Bing API key in order to test this, so don't get terribly excited until you test it yourself.

I suspect that what is going on is that Bing is using what it thinks is your current location to determine what Bedford and Shuttleworth mean.  So if it thinks you are in England, you get Bedford and Shuttleworth England, and if you are in some other part of the world that has a Bedford and a Shuttleworth, it picks those.  I'm in Texas and I got the 11.9 mile route you want.  So maybe Bing is smart enough to know that in every part of the world except near the 182-mile-apart Bedford and Shuttleworth, people really are looking for the English ones.  I'm guessing that the server where your code is is near the wrong Bedford and Shuttleworth.

So I was looking at the API, and at [Bing API User Context Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701704.aspx) is documented the UserLocation parameter, where you can put in your latitude and longitude to help Bing make decisions.  Try adding that parameter to your query and putting in your actual longitude and latitude, or, if that fails, try putting in one for Austin, TX, USA (where I am) or one that is smack dab between the Bedford and Shuttleworth you are interested in.